# transfer data between databases - influx-python

Tags: python, influxdb

I am trying to write points that been taken from one database to another (influxdb-python), I have created a list of dict, and I am using write_points('list of dicts'). I even tried to simplify things by getting only 2 points.

here is my code and the errors, pls help

```
rs = cli.query("""SELECT * FROM cpu_value WHERE time > now() - 2s""")
points = rs.get_points()
a=next(points)
b=next(points)
temp=[]
temp.append(a)
temp.append(b)

client = InfluxDBClient(database='test')

client.write_points(temp)
```

[image]

Comment: I see code but no errors. Hard to tell what isn't working without the error output.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to use the [INTO clause](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.9/query_language/data_exploration/#the-into-clause) to write from one database to another, rather than exporting and importing the points via an external library.

Comment: That doesn't work if you need to convert strings to ints or floats (something which influxdb can't do)